# Reading a Crash Log iOS

Tags: objective-c, xml, memory-management, crash

Apparently my apps crashes when using the live server. I'm downloading XML when a user changed the mapregion. The server returns data for the boundingbox and my apps shows the annotation. However when a place has a url variable set my app just crashes. It doesnt even break on a exception breakpoint but just goes straight to main.m.

My device crash log looks like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f1fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0d6a4e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b020028 abort + 72
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3b09d758 szone_error + 312
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3b09da1a free_tiny_botch + 62
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30692fd6 CFRelease + 890
6   APPName                         0x0011ef04 -[MyPlaceClass dealloc] (MyPlaceClass.mm:650)
7   APPName                         0x0011f684 -[MyTextPlace dealloc] (MyTextPlace.m:46)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aacab06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30692e88 CFRelease + 556
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3069e3b4 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 156
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aacab06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aabc01e (anonymous             namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
13  CoreFoundation                  0x306961c4 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
14  UIKit                           0x32edf80c _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 32
15
```

I checked (MyPlaceClass.mm:650) and (MyTextPlace.m:46). And that just looks like this:

MyPlaceClass.mm on line 650

```
- (void)dealloc {
    .....
    [placeURL release]; // <- This is line 650
    [super dealloc];
}
```

MyTextPlace.m on line 46

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [textContent release]; // <- This is line 46
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Does somebody know whats causing my error and crash on my device? I find it really hard te debug because my exception breakpoints just dont work.

Comment: what is the datatypes of textContent and placeURL?

Comment: My guess is that `placeURL` is already released and the pointer is left dangling. Releasing it again cause a segfault

Comment: show me allocations of textContent and placeURL

Comment: Yes placeURL has already been released.... stupid but thanks for all your help! (maybe posting it as an answer so I can accept it?)

Comment: Start using ARC instead of Non-ARC

Comment: Yes really need to do that. Is a to do for 2014

Comment: It may sounds obvious, and you probably already did that, but have you tried to run the app within instrumentation with both **Leaks** and **Allocation template** ?

Comment: I did though. It's just that I'm used to work with ARC and this project is built without it. I should update it soon. Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

placeURL was already being released.